# Hacer UPDATE a un dato MYSQL via PHP con valor similar desde el mismo query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Mi consulta en esta oportunidad es saber si es posible efectuar un **UPDATE** a una base de datos desde **MySQL** donde al valor existente en la base de datos solo se le agregue una letra 
Mi query es el siguiente:

```
$query = "UPDATE pedidos SET
    status_pedido = '$status',
    motivo_rechazo = '$motivo',
    fecha_rechazo = '$fecha_act'
    WHERE id = '$id'";
```

dentro de la tabla pedidos hay un parámetro que se llama nro_trans y es un indice o una key secundaria y quisiera ejemplo al dato existente agregarle la letra **R** indicativo de rechazo.
Dato existente = 123456
Dato Actualizado = R123456

quisiera saber si hay una forma de hacerlo directamente en mi query u obligatoriamente debo hacer un segundo query para recuperar ese dato previamente..?

Comment: a cual columna le vas a aplicar la actuialización?

Comment: Se llama `nro_trans`

Comment: pero en tu update no la veo, el cambio es a motivo_rechazo no?

Comment: no asi como esta mi query esta haciendo la actualizacion a los columnas indicadas alli, pero quisiera hacerle tambien un UPDATE a la columna `nro_trans` pero solo agregarle una **R** al dato existente en esa columna

Comment: Es decir al dato existente si fuera 123456 actualizarlo a R123456

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres alterar la llave poniéndole una letra? Haciendo eso pierdes tu llave ¿no? ¿Por qué mejor no añades una columna de tamaño `CHAR(1)` para poner la `R`, o de tipo `TINYINT` con códigos numéricos. Si algún día te piden una relación de los tipos `R`echazo u otros... entonces vas a tener que trabajar tu llave alterada para buscar solamente la primera letra que agregaste. No conozco bien tu contexto, pero a simple vista parece poco práctico lo que intentas hacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías probar usando la función `CONCAT()` para indicar al incio el valor que le quieres agregar que es la letra `R`

Entonces para tu requerimiento debería verse así:

```
nro_trans = CONCAT('R', nro_trans);
```

1. Donde nro_trans es el mismo valor solo que le vamos a añadir la letra R al inicio
2. Primero dentro del `CONCAT` añado la letra R para que la concatene al inicio del valor que deseas actualizar

[Aquí te dejo un enlace a la documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), donde puedes leer que `CONCAT` acepta desde uno a mas parámetros